# A trigonometric problem

Tags: trigonometry, pi, trigonometric-series

$$2 (\cos{⁡2x} )(\sin ⁡2x-1)=\sqrt{3} \cos{⁡4}x$$
I have tried to reduce this equation and I got this: $\cos(4x+\pi/6)=-\cos2x$ but I don't know how to do next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that:
$$\cos(a)=\cos(b) \leftrightarrow a=b+\pi+2k\pi \vee a+b=\pi+2k\pi$$
Here $a=4x+\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $b=-2x$ because we know that $-\cos(2x)=\cos(-2x)$
In the first case, we have:
$$4x+\frac{\pi}{6}=\pi-2x+2k\pi \leftrightarrow x=\frac{5\pi}{36}+\frac{k\pi}{3}$$
In the second case, we obtain:
$$4x+\frac{\pi}{6}-2x=\pi+2k\pi \leftrightarrow x=\frac{5\pi}{12}+k\pi$$

Comment: Thank you for helping me!

Comment: @Tiago: if this answer has been useful maybe a $+1$ or a favourite answer?

Comment: I have voted an upvote for you, but I don't have enough reputations.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

You can write $\;-\cos2x=\cos (2x+\pi)$ and use that
$$ \cos\theta=\cos\varphi\iff \theta\equiv \pm\varphi \pmod{2\pi}. $$

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can use this because there is a minus sign in $\cos(4x+\pi/6)=-\cos2x$. Thank you!

Comment: The  minus sign has been taken into account with $\cos(2x \color{red}{{}+\pi})$.

Comment: Oh, I see, my bad. Thank you very much!